# Get Field Names from Dependency Protobuf files in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have Protobuf structure of abc.proto like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "auditData.proto";
import "Date.proto";
import "column_name.proto";

message abc {
    AuditData auditData = 1;
    int32 field2 = 2;
    Date date=3;
    column_name colnm=4
}
```

I have converted to abc_pb2.py.
How to get Field Names for AuditData, Date and column_names just by giving abc input in python. because i have too many files and dependency, manually doing is not possible.

I have installed protobuf module: 3.19.4

Answer (score 1):

To properly use your generated `auditData.proto` module, you'll first need to import it into your code. Then, construct the `AuditData` class to populate the `auditData` field as shown below:

First, import the generated modules. (This assumes that your protobuf files are located at the same hierarchy level.)

```py
from abc_pb2 import abc
from auditData_pb2 import AuditData
```

To use the classes, proceed as follows:

```py
audit_data = AuditData(
  #...
)
data = abc(auditData=audit_data)
```

Maintaining well-organized protobuf files without introducing breaking changes can be challenging, especially if your dependencies (e.g., `auditData.proto`) are located in other remote repositories. In such cases, my suggestion is to clone these dependencies into a higher-level directory like `protos` alongside your custom protobuf files. Continue to compile them as usual using the command `python -m grpc_tools.protoc -Iprotos --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=.`. Notice that we added the protobuf "source" directory to the `-I` flag of `protoc`.

While this approach works, it can be cumbersome and repetitive. This is one of the pain points in the protobuf ecosystem that could use improvement.

Though you didn't ask for tool recommendations, if you're working within a local workspace (e.g., collaborating with teammates on the same repository), you might find my open-source CLI tool [`sylk`](https://sylk.build/) useful. It simplifies protobuf management without requiring you to dive into `protoc` commands every time you compile protobuf files `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

If you rely on remote repositories, however, `sylk` currently doesn't support Git integration. In that case, you might want to consider [`buf`](https://buf.build/), which can help manage remote dependencies.

I hope this clarifies some of the challenges in the protobuf ecosystem. It's an area ripe for improvement, and new tools are beginning to address these issues.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of the Sylk CLI tool, an open-source project. PRs to enhance its features are more than welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the fields in a message, then if it is a message, iterate through that messages fields, something like:

```
# For every field in the message
    for field in message.fields:
        # Check for nested types
        if field.cpp_type == FieldDescriptor.CPPTYPE_MESSAGE and field.message_type.name in message.nested_types_by_name:
            for nested_field in field.message_type.fields:
                # Do stuff, print nested_field.name, etc
```